# Adjunction of two functors. If the right adjoint functor is linear, then the left adjoint functor is also linear.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $R$ be a Ring, $M$ be the category of R modules, and $(L,R, \tau)$ an adjunction from $M$ to $M$  such that $R$ is linear $(F(f+g)=F(f)+F(g))$. I want to show that $L$ is also linear. I would just like a hint - I don't see how I can use the special property of two adjoint functors here.

Thank you

Comment: Actually, any left or right adjoint functor between additive categories is additive.

Answer (score 0):

if we denote the unit and the counit of the adjunction by $\eta$ and $\varepsilon$ respectively, the triangle identity $L(\varepsilon_X)\circ\eta_{L(X)}=id_{L(X)}$ is natural in $X\in M$. if $f,g:X\to Y$ are two morphisms in $M$, start with $L(f)+L(g):L(X)\to L(Y)$. after applying $\eta_{L}$ you get $LR(L(f)+L(g))$, which by the linearity of $R$ is $L(RL(f)+RL(g))$. now apply $L\varepsilon$ and we get $L(f+g)$. by the triangle identity this is $L(f)+L(g)$.